# Install submodule using jitpack

Tags: android, jitpack

I'm using Nordic's Android DFU package in my project, but it has a bug. I found there is a fork that fix that bug but I'm having trouble installing the packing using **jitpack.io**

Link to the fix: https://github.com/brianherold/Android-DFU-Library/tree/fix-for-issue-358

The DFU module is a submodule of the whole project
the content of `setting.gradle.kts`

```
...
include(":app")
include(":lib:analytics")
include(":lib:dfu") <<< this is the submodule that I want
...
```

What I have tried:

`implement 'com.github.brianherold.Android-DFU-Library:lib_dfu:fix-for-issue-358-SNAPSHOT'`

and

`implement 'com.github.brianherold.Android-DFU-Library:lib:dfu:fix-for-issue-358-SNAPSHOT'`

and

`implement 'com.github.brianherold.Android-DFU-Library.lib:dfu:fix-for-issue-358-SNAPSHOT'`

All of these command gradle return the message `Failed to resolve ...`

Please guide me to the correct command, Thank you

Comment: If you already have it as a submodule then simply `implementation(project(":lib:dfu")) should work. Have you tried this?